# Searching for and printing two key words in set

Tags: grep, set

If I have a list like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
```

Is there a command where I can specify for `aaa` and `bbb`?
I know if I want to search for aaa I can do: `sed -n '/aaa/p'`
But is there a way I can search for `bbb` at the same time as I am searching for `aaa`?
Something like this? `sed -n '/aaa/bbb/p'`

Comment: `grep -E 'aaa|bbb' file`? `sed -nE '/aaa|bbb/p' file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution with GNU and FreeBSD `sed`:

```
s='aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg'
sed -nE '/aaa|bbb/p' <<< "$s"
```

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/ikuJVM). Here, `E` option enables the POSIX ERE syntax and `|` means an alternation inside the regex pattern.

Another portable way with `-e` to chain `sed` commands:

```
sed -n -e '/aaa/p' -e '/bbb/p'
```